# React-admin SelectInput does not show the value in Edit using together with choises

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-admin

I have a status field, coming from my API. It has a value between 0-3.

my response looks like this:

```
{ status: 0 }
```

I can show the value in Edit with TextInput, it shows the value (in this case 0).

However I want it to show it with SelectInput, as in Edit mode I want to change the value of the status.

my SelectInput looks like this:

```
          <SelectInput label="Status" source="status" choices={[
                       { id: '0', name: 'elfogadásra vár' },
                       { id: '1', name: 'aktív' },
                       { id: '2', name: 'inaktív' },
                       { id: '3', name: 'archív' },
                       ]} 
                       optionText="name" 
                       optionValue="id" 
          />
```

Unfortunately when I save this, and refresh my page, my Status does not show the current value (which is 0 in this case, it should show me 'elfogadasra var', but it's empty)

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The way i achieved this was in the following manner

```
<ReferenceInput label="Country" source='country.id' reference="Country"  sort={{ field: 'name', order: 'ASC' }} alwaysOn>
   <SelectInput optionText="name" optionValue="id" allowEmpty />
</ReferenceInput>
```

I needed to load my choices from that database though however the concept is the same... i suspect that what you are using for source is wrong.. Look in the redux dev tools.. under state --> form --> record-form --> values and you should see something like status.id that you should be using for source instead.. i have the same type of object in my form country {id: 2}... but that is not what you use to get the input to show your existing value...

Your solution may be as simple as calling a diff value in source, but you'll know what that should be by peeking into the state {status: 0} must have something in front of it in state like something --> {status: 0}

Comment: Not sure I fully understand you ... why TextInput shows correctly my value (in this case 0), and why SelectInput not? Both works from the same API response

Comment: Yeah but your text input is simply showing the 0 associated with the property named source....  you have tuples associated with your select input, so it has no idea what to do with the value when you supply just a 0 to it... did you look in your form record?  maybe paste the values info fully opened

Comment: found the issue - for some reason I had a customInput that prevented SelectInput working properly. Once I removed that custom input, my SelectInput is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Not the real reason but in case somebody is tackling with the same issue it is worth checking:

I found out I was passing `initialValues` to the `Form` component on `create` and haven't skipped them on the `edit` mode. That's why it was always resetting the `SelectInput`'s.